# Lagrange multiplier constrictions equality

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

if I have $f(x,y,z)=\cdots $ and two constrictions $g(x,y,z)$ ,  $h(x,y,z)$

and I need to calculate the min/max etc.

(1)  I know that I can do a Lagrange system with $5$ equations and $5$ variables.

(2)  if I do two systems separately (one with $g(x,y,z)$ and the other one with $h(x,y,z)$) will it give me the same results as if I were to do them as point 1?

(3) if my $f(x,y,z)=z$ and let $g(x,y,z)$ be the constraint. Can I still do Lagrange multiplier even though $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(2) Of course not (in general). Suppose that $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$, that the first constrain is $x=-1$ and that the second constrain is $y=-1$. If you solve two systems separately, then the solution of the first system will be $(-1,0,0)$, whereas the solution of the second one will be $(0,-1,0)$. None of these points belong to the line $x=y=-1$. The solution will be $(-1,-1,0)$, of course.

(3) Yes, you can.

Comment: In (3):  that means that if I found a point is in the form (x,y,z)=(x,y,point_found) or (z)=(point_found) ? I originally asked that question becouse:  lets assume I find a possible critical point (z)=(3) and I want to find if it is a max or min extrema , I procede doing the second derivate test ... But wait it doesn't work on f(x,y,z)=z because f_xx =0 = f_yy

Comment: But that test is for functions defined on an open set. That's not the case here.

Comment: Could you give me an example please? Because I really have trouble understanding the min/max of constrained  functions like f(x,y,z)='one variable'  , like f(x,y,z)=e^x , f(x,y,z)=y .

Comment: Suppose that your afte that maximum and the minimum of $z$ in the region $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Then you solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}0=2\lambda x\\0=2\lambda y\\1=2\lambda z\\x^2+y^2+z^2=1.\end{array}\right.$$This system only has $2$ solutions: $(x,y,z,\lambda)=\pm\left(0,0,1,\frac12\right)$. So, you see what's the value of $z$ when $(x,y,z)=(0,0,\pm1)$ and you deduce that the maximum and the minimum are attained at $(0,0,1)$ and at $(0,0,-1)$ respectively.

Comment: So in order to decide if it is a max or min I only have the 'deduction' method ?

Comment: @NPLS I don't know what that is. What I do is to check what happens at the points that I get when I solve the system.

Comment: with 'deduction' method I intend your method -> (0,0,1) 1 is positive so it must be a maximum and on the other hand (0,0,-1) is  a minimum because -1 is a negative number. How do I know (0,0,1) isn't a saddle point ?

Comment: @NPLS Because there has to be a maximum (since our set is compact) and every local extreme has to be a solution of the system. Note that there aren't other soltutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your patience :)